# How to change the name of a logical drive using C#?

Tags: c#

I know by now how to get all the logical drives, how to create one and destroy it.

It is very important to me to know how to modify the label of the logical drive.
Let's say the disk label is NewDisk, and I created a logical disk that maps a certain path in NewDisk. Then, the letter for this logical disk is, let's say M, but its label is NewDisk (it appears as "NewDisk (M:)").

How then can I change the label for logical drive M to be something other than "NewDisk", using C# ?

Thanks

Comment: Disks have *labels*... Not exactly clear what you mean "name of logical drive"... presumably you've used `subst` to map some path to folder - please [edit] your post to clarify (such mapping does not have its own label as it is not a disk)...

Comment: "Let's say the disk name is NewDisk, and I created a logical disk that maps a certain path in NewDisk" -- this sounds like a *virtual drive*, and their name isn't exactly changeable. If you double click a virtual drive and assign a volume lable it just gives an error. A trick is that you can right click the drive and go to "rename" and it will *display* a name that looks like a volume label, but really it's just a registry key created under the current user. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST#Custom_label) you can edit HKLM  for the label which I assume goes to all users.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I don't need to do this using subst as there is a working solution using C# (as I mention in the first sentence of my question). Sorry for "misleading" when used the word NAME instead of LABEL. So from what you are saying, there is no way to modify the logical drive's LABEL ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want VolumeLabel on the DriveInfo class ... [DriveInfo Class at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DriveInfo.GetDrives MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried to set the VolumeLabel property of the DriveInfo instance of the virtual drive I created but an IOException is thrown - "The directory is not a subdirectory of the root directory.".

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832065.aspx), you'll have to try a different subdirectory. I'm not sure this will work with virtual drives.